# Create and/or update tab in Chrome in active window

Tags: google-chrome-extension

my chrome extension creates a certain number of tabs and after it, they gets updated everytime I want it. Its working flawless.

Now: If I run a new instance of chrome, the "old" tabs are updated. I want, that the extension creates new ones and update them in the new instance. The extension should create and update their tabs in every instance for its own. It's possible?

My Code for create

```
if (!globalData.started) {
            if (globalData.bb) {
                chrome.tabs.create({url: URL}, function(tab){
                globalData.bbId = tab.id;
                });
                .
                .
                .
                globalData.started = true;
```

and update:

```
if (globalData.bb) {chrome.tabs.update(globalData.bbId, {url: URL});};
```

Comment: Can you show the code that creates new tabs?

Comment: Omg.... 3rd line?